# Wordpress theme custom capabilities not works

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, capabilities

I have created custom post type `listings` and defined some capabilities to it.But when adding capabilities it does not works.

### Custom post

```
register_post_type('listings', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => __('Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'singular_name' => __('Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'thefoody') ,
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'edit' => __('Edit', 'thefoody') ,
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'new_item' => __('New Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'view' => __('View Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'view_item' => __('View Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
        'search_items' => __('Search Restaurant listings', 'thefoody') ,
        'not_found' => __('No Restaurant listings found', 'thefoody') ,
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Restaurant listings found in Trash', 'thefoody') ,
        'parent' => __('Parent Restaurant listing', 'thefoody') ,
    ) ,
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail'
    ) ,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone',
    'capability_type'   => 'listings',
    'capabilities' => array(
        'edit_post'             => 'edit_restaurant',
        'edit_others_posts'     => 'edit_others_restaurants',
        'publish_posts'         => 'publish_restaurants',
        'read_post'             => 'read_restaurant',
        'read_private_posts'    => 'read_private_restaurants',
        'delete_posts'          => 'delete_restaurants',
        'delete_others_posts'   => 'delete_others_restaurants',
    ),
));
```

And my codes to add capabilities:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    $role_shop_manager = get_role( 'shop_manager' );
    $role_shop_manager->add_cap( 
                            'edit_restaurants', 
                            'publish_restaurants', 
                            'view_posts', 
                            'delete_post', 
                            'delete_published_posts', 
                            'delete_restaurant' 
                        ); 
    $role_shop_manager->remove_cap( 'edit_others_restaurants', 'edit_others_posts' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_gallery' );
function register_cpt_gallery() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name'          => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Gallery', 'gallery' ),
        'add_new'       => _x( 'Add New', 'gallery' ),
        'add_new_item'  => _x( 'Add New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
        'edit_item'     => _x( 'Edit Gallery', 'gallery' ),
        'new_item'      => _x( 'New Gallery', 'gallery' ),
        'view_item'     => _x( 'View Gallery', 'gallery' ),
        'search_items'  => _x( 'Search Galleries', 'gallery' ),
        'not_found'     => _x( 'No galleries found', 'gallery' ),
        'menu_name'     => _x( 'Galleries', 'gallery' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => _x( 'No galleries found in Trash', 'gallery' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => _x( 'Parent Gallery:', 'gallery' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'description'   => 'Image galleries for teachers classes',
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author' ),
        'public'        => true,
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'show_in_menu'  => true,
        'menu_icon'     => get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/images/imagegallery.png',
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'can_export'    => true,
        'rewrite'       => true,
        'capabilities'  => array(
            'edit_post'          => 'edit_gallery',
            'edit_posts'         => 'edit_galleries',
            'edit_others_posts'  => 'edit_other_galleries',
            'publish_posts'      => 'publish_galleries',
            'read_post'          => 'read_gallery',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_galleries',
            'delete_post'        => 'delete_gallery'
        ),

        // as pointed out by iEmanuele, adding map_meta_cap will map the meta correctly 
        'map_meta_cap'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    );

     register_post_type( 'gallery', $args );
}
```

The additional capabilities should be added to a role for the permissions to actually work in the backend, including the 'administrator' - for example:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
    // gets the administrator role
    $admins = get_role( 'administrator' );

    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_gallery' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'edit_other_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'publish_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_gallery' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'read_private_galleries' ); 
    $admins->add_cap( 'delete_gallery' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps');
```